# Python requests.get raises ConnectionError for HTTPS url

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests

im trying this simple python 2.7 code:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(url="https://sslbl.abuse.ch", verify=False)
print response
```

I'm using `verify=False` in order to ignore verifying the SSL certificate.
I'm getting the following exception:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sslbl.abuse.ch', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

If I try another https url (like twitter.com) everything is ok.
What can be the problem? How can I get the response like a browser does?

UPDATE:
after upgrading requests version i get the same `ConnectionError` but some warnings were added:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
```

Comment: what version of requests?

Comment: Why don't you use urllib.request in Python3x? Please see my suggested answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Python 2.7 for my tasks, but I tried to open the URL you provided with python3.2 (it should work for all Python3x, I assume). There was no exception raised. This is what I did (>>> are omited):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = "https://sslbl.abuse.ch"
response = urlopen(url)
type(response)
<class 'http.client.HTTPResponse'>
```

From the Python docs, see the output of this:

```
i = 0
with open(url) as response:
    for line in response:
        line = line.decode('utf-8')
        if "Show more information about this SSL certificate" in line:
        i += 1
print(i)
1060
```

I suggest using Python3x. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I must use python 27 because of job place requirements.